# installation of custom library cdata for python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to install custom library cdata for python. This library enables connection over C4C Hybris.

Unfortunately, system generates the following error while pip list (of anaconda) shows this library installed :

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gExt.jpg)
[cdata library is installed in anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEffz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem while installing a different package, must be because of 2 different versions of python installed in your system. One solution is -
Uninstall Python from Control Panel
Uninstall Pycharm
Reinstall the latest version of both.

**Better** solution is changing the interpreter for that, you should go to Pycharm --> file> settings> project>project interpreter.

If there is another Python Instance, it should be up there, change it to that one. If its not in the list, click on the button that looks like Asterik/star (next to project interpreter).

CHange the interpreter.

`conda update conda`

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

No errors will be observed thereafter.

Moreover, read about Anaconda Virtual Envs, it will help you in long tun.